# C# opensource obfuscator (Obfuscar) doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I've tried to use Obfuscator, my minimum config is:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Obfuscator>
  <Var name="InPath" value=".\Obfuscator_Input" />
  <Var name="OutPath" value=".\Obfuscator_Output" />

  <Module file="$(InPath)\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe" /> 
</Obfuscator>
```

UPD: Maybe config itself is not enough, i should create .proj file, but there is nothing like example of this file with programm. There is large example file in source code archive, but still can't understand what should i took from there or how to generate this file by myself.
I've run the program, but when i opened binary with ILspy, i saw that the code is actually the same as in non-obfuscated version. Why is that happening?

Comment: I'd recommend you re-read this articel and use the dotobfuscator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977082%28v=vs.107%29.aspx

Comment: But I'am using opensoucre obfuscator as i mentioned in question's title.

Comment: and which one? Link ?

Comment: Its obfuscar, https://obfuscar.codeplex.com. My bad, will edit the post to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConfuserEx did the job perfectly (used GUI version with no need to craft rule file by my own).

Comment: this is not the solution. besides this i don't use the confuserEx anymore. itself doesn't have any virus or malware but all anti-virus programs detects it as virus because of attackers uses confuserEx for obfuscate their code and that's why now, all av detects programs that obfuscated with confuserEx as a virus..

Comment: @Aura, what is the solution then?

Comment: @ivanpetrow i didn't post this comment as a solution like you did above. For an example to use Obfuscar, you can find it out from this link that shared by developer : https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Example&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: @aura, obfuscar is poorly documented, i didn't find any good tutorial how to create rules and use it on your own project.

Comment: #ivanpetrow, you are right, yesterday i sent an email to developer and even the response was poor. he told me to check example page and learn MsBuild.  by the way, what obfuscator are you using now for your codes? i'm still looking a obfuscator.

Comment: @Aura, when it was a need I've used ConfuserEx with hardcore encoding. It worked pretty well.